# Can you clone an anonymous object? (Java / OOP)

Tags: java, class, clone, anonymous

I'm creating a library of very common, very simple shapes. Sphere would be a member, as well as torus, and so on. Torus has two radius fields, whereas sphere has one; that modified behavior is something we can provide by changing the implementation of functions to include both radii, and of course, adding the extra radius field. Torus is common enough that inclusion of that behavior in the permanent library is beneficial.

On the other hand, "WigglyTorus", a torus whose radii oscillate, would not be a member of the permanent library. Instead, an anonymous class is more useful; it can store the desired behavior just as well, but externally, it is treated just like an ordinary torus.

Therein lies the problem. If I want to clone a torus, my new torus can behave exactly the same. If I want to clone a WigglyTorus, the reproduced behaviors will mimic the behaviors of torus, and I don't really have a clone at all. But two uses of WigglyTorus does not justify the addition of WigglyTorus as a permanent class.

I've thought about workarounds, but none of them seem elegant. I feel like I'm missing something significant about either Java or OOP.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by clone? Calling the `clone()` method or creating more instances?

Comment: Not necessarily with clone(), but hypothetically. Should I be implementing the clone() function differently in each anonymous object I create?

Comment: It might be easier to post your attempts so we can get an idea.

Comment: _"But two uses of WigglyTorus does not justify the addition of WigglyTorus as a permanent class"_ -- why not? It costs you nothing.  You could make it the constructor private if you don't want users creating copies, and return them as `Torus` instances from a factory.

Comment: What if a wiggly torus is just an instance of a normal torus but has an eventListener added to it. An UpdateListener, that's called on every update of the simulation/game and has a delta time passed into it.

Comment: I suppose it works to create a class for everything - it just means I'll have a folder full of subclasses for test objects.
@SpiderPig, time is a static field in a super class. The problem is cloning objects which change their implementation, or their fields. It sounds like it isn't really possible.

Comment: But I told you how it's possible. Put the parts of the implementation that change into listeners that you add to your objects. Every method definition can always be replaced by a listener, which can easily be copied.