# Cloning an instantiated abstract class

Tags: java, android, abstract

*Instantiate an abstract class. -> Duplicate it, preserving the implementation of the abstract method.*

```
    public abstract class Foo{… 

    public int myVar;

    public abstract void do();

     }//Foo
```

elsewhere in package:

```
public class Gha{ … 

    Foo testFoo = new Foo{

        @Override
        public void do(){
            Log.i("" , "this is a special Foo"); //executable process
        }//do

    }//testFoo
    …
}//Gha
```

**Can I copy `testFoo` in a way that copies `testFoo`’s `.do()` method body for the new `Foo`?**

Comment: You cannot call a method `do`. Why do you need to do this? What is the point in having two separate instances for executing the same block of code?

Comment: Mind adding indentation to your code snippets? It's very hard to read.

Comment: Ty. Attempted to make the code more readable. @Egor

Comment: @PaulBoddington I'm using many `Foo` and they each have a different method of reacting. They are also used as instance variables, and I need to make a deep copy.

Comment: Not...really?  Objects are not, in general, copyable.  Without a named class, you're almost certainly out of luck.  Besides, the `Foo` in your example appears stateless, so there wouldn't be any point in copying it anyway?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188882/can-you-clone-an-anonymous-object-java-oop

Comment: @azurefrog Thanks, I'll edit. Wrote these snippets just to post here. The actual code uses the proper `"`

Comment: @azurefrog good catch. It's not an exact duplicate, but the difference is minor enough that I think functionally it's the same::  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188882/can-you-clone-an-anonymous-object-java-oop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `clone`. The use of this method is widely discouraged, but it does work.

For example:

```
public abstract class Foo implements Cloneable {

    private int a;
    private String b;

    public Foo(int a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    } 

    public abstract void run();

    public int getA() { return a; }

    public String getB() { return b; }

    @Override
    public final Foo clone() {
        try {
            return (Foo) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(); // Can't happen
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can do:

```
Foo original = new Foo(3, "bar") {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
};
Foo copy = original.clone();
System.out.println(copy.getA());
System.out.println(copy.getB());
copy.run();
System.out.println(copy == original);
```

The output is:

```
3
bar
Hello, world!
false
```

An alternative is to use `Serializable`.

```
public abstract class Foo implements Serializable {

    private int a;
    private String b;

    public Foo(int a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public abstract void run();

    public int getA() { return a; }

    public String getB() { return b; }

    public final Foo copy() {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            new ObjectOutputStream(baos).writeObject(this);
            return (Foo) new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())).readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(); 
        }
    }
}
```

With this version, replace `clone` by `copy` and you'll get the same result.

Comment: Clone seems like a good fit. I really like your first solution. Thank you. I'll poke around to find out why it's so discouraged. I never really explored it before.

Comment: @Scottie I recommend Effective Java by Josh Bloch. There's an excellent section on `clone`. The main irritation is that `clone` is not `public`, so if you have a `List<? extends Cloneable>` you can't actually make a deep copy, because you can't call `clone` on the elements. It's ridiculous.

Comment: @Scottie Josh Bloch doesn't like it, nuff said :P

Comment: Thanks, I will pick it up!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this...

```
public class TestFoo extends Foo{

    private static String TAG = TestFoo.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void do(){
        Log.i(getTag() , “this is a special Foo”); //executable process
    }

    protected String getTag(){
        return TAG;
    }
}
```

And then instantiate TestFoo objects that will perform do(). If you want a separate Tag for each instance you can override the getTag() function in the instanted class. Not sure if this is what you need but a lot easier to explain than a comment :P

**NOTE**

If this is something you would be doing in a lot of places, and you don't want to subclass all over the place (mentioned in the comments) please look at Paul Boddington's answer, particularly the copy portion.

Comment: Yep, that would work, thank you. That's actually how it's now, but I was/ am trying to cut down on the clutter of a whole pile of sub-classed `Foo`s.

Comment: @Scottie It sounds like you may want to sit down and rethink how you are working your app. If Foo get's overridden by a bunch of subclasses you should just use an interface.

Comment: The actual `Foo` would have instance variables. I will update the question.   @zgc7009

Comment: @Scottie What is the purpose of the var? If the purpose of the var is to use it in do, just pass it to do as a parameter and return whatever you need instead of void.

Comment: I missed it on first read. Never thought to use the `getSimpleName()` . I think this solves my issue. I'll store all the method bodies in a separate resource file and call them based on a switch. Thanks so much! EDIT: actually, no it doesn't, but adding a int flag and then sending to a switch would. Thanks for putting me on the right track. ;) Still kinda awkward, but functional.